# Optimizing word ladder

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to solve this question:

> Given two words (beginWord and endWord), and a dictionary's word list,
>   find the length of shortest transformation sequence from beginWord to
>   endWord, such that:
>
> Only one letter can be changed at a time. Each transformed word must
>   exist in the word list. Note that beginWord is not a transformed word.
>   Note:
>
> Return 0 if there is no such transformation sequence. All words have
>   the same length. All words contain only lowercase alphabetic
>   characters. You may assume no duplicates in the word list. You may
>   assume beginWord and endWord are non-empty and are not the same.

https://leetcode.com/problems/word-ladder/
My correct working code:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict, deque 
def can_change(x, y):
    diff = 0
    for u, v in zip(x, y):
        if u != v:
            diff += 1
        if diff>1:
            return False
    return diff == 1


class Solution:
    def ladderLength(self, start, end, dict):
        graph = defaultdict(list)
        words = set(dict+[start])
        for w1 in words:
            for w2 in words:
                if w1 != w2:
                    if can_change(w1, w2):
                        graph[w1].append(w2)
        def bfs(node):
            queue = deque([(node, 1)])
            seen = {node}
            while queue:
                node, count = queue.pop()
                if node == end:
                    return count
                for neb in graph[node]:
                    if neb not in seen:
                        seen.add(neb)
                        queue.appendleft((neb, count+1))
            return 0
        return bfs(start)
```

This times out on big test cases. How do I optimize in terms of time complexity?

Comment: You probably should post this question in the code review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would try to avoid explicitly defining the graph using adjacency lists - I think it is redundant.

Instead, you could try to implicitly run BFS.
Pseudo-code:

```
Q = empty queue 
beginWord.depth = 0
Q.enqueue(beginWord)  
while  Q is not empty:
    w = Q.dequeue
    for l in dictionary:
        if l is a one char transform on w:
              if l == endWord:
                  return w.depth+1 
              else:
                  l.depth = w + 1
                  Q.enqueue(l)
                  remove l from the dictionary.
return 0
```

This method is very similar to the BFS method you have used, I think. It scans the "graph" in a BFS manner, keeping track of the words found reachable from the beginWord, and the current depth of search. If it finds the endWord, it returns its depth.

The main difference here is that we do not create a graph to model the whole dictionary. We do scan the breadth-first-style search, but we avoid keeping track of information we don't use  later - such as edges on the path, unreachable words, etc.

The asymptotic running time here is O(nX), X being the number of words reachable from beginWord. It does not beat your algorithm in the worst case scenario, but it does on many other cases.

It also saves you the BFS search you had to perform after building the graph, and takes words that has been proved reachable out of the list, and thus reduce constants.